# setcellValue limitations in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Im using setcellValue to populate my excel file, but the moment it reaches A99, it throws this error

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Column string index can not be longer than 3 characters.'
```

is it a limitation that phpexcel has, or am i making a mistake by populating my sheet in this format

```
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setcellValue($alpha[$alpha_count] . $spreadsheet_count, $row['comment']);
```

Comment: I think `$alpha[$alpha_count] . $spreadsheet_count` musn't be longer than 3 chars. What's the content of these variables?

Comment: **$alpha** is just a normal letter, **$spreadsheet_count** is the row number, i get this error when i reach A100, which is more then 3 characters yes, but does that mean phpexcel only supports 100 rows?

Comment: @mimipc - it means that the value of $alpha[$alpha_count] can't be more than three characters

Comment: $alpha[$alpha_count] is always just 1 letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try with setCellValueByColumnAndRow() :

```
setCellValueByColumnAndRow($alpha_count, $spreadsheet_count, $row['comment']);
```

Comment: Yep, this is much better, so i guess now my limit is 999 rows?

Comment: Not sure. Try `setCellValueByColumnAndRow(99999, 99999, 'FooBar');`

Comment: 16,384 is the max column in Excel 2010, so setting column to 99999 is kinda silly

Comment: I didn't know 16,384 was the maximum, but anyway, my comment meant you can just try it yourself to know if you can put more than 3 chars...

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't mean that that PHPExcel supports only 100 rows, PHPExcel supports up to 1,048,576 rows and up to 16,384 columns (same as the OfficeOpenXML format for xlsx files)... dependent on memory.

Your `column string index` that the error message refers to is the column reference (the `A` of `A100`).

Double check exactly what the value of $alpha[$alpha_count] is, I suspect it isn't what you think.

Comment: $alpha[$alpha_count] is always just 1 letter

Comment: In that case, you're the first person to encounter this major bug... can you please provide some more code to help me investigate and fix... I need to identify why the code logic is failing in this case

Comment: Are you calling PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString() anywhere in your script? If so, can you please provide details of that part of your code

Comment: nope, im not calling it, i simply use the setcellValue function with the letter and row number concatenated as the first parameter, and the value of the cell in the second like shown above

Comment: Weirder and weirder. So far I'm unable to replicate the problem; but that error is only thrown by PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString() and setCellValue() doesn't call that method at all.

Comment: i get the same error when using this **$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($alpha[$alpha_count] . $spreadsheet_count)->setWidth(34);**. but only when **$spreadsheet_count** wich is the row goes over a hundred, thus making the value A100, 4 characters long

Comment: You will get that error if you're calling getColumnDimension() with a cell reference, it wants a column reference only ($alpha[$alpha_count] in your case), not the row reference part as well, and validates that it is only a column reference

Comment: Ok my mistake with that one, since im only suppose to provide the column